# Spark gracefully stop and exit(1)

Tags: apache-spark

I run a spark application as `yarn-cluster` mode.

What I have a difficult is, I can't stop spark gracefully then exit(1) the submition to fail the jenkins job.

## Shell script executed by jenkins

```
/bin/spark-submit \
    --master yarn-cluster \
   ...
```

## Spark Application

```
val sparkSession = ...
val resultDataframe = ...

if(resultDataframe.count() == 0){
  // lets stop spark
  sparkSession.stop()
  // I want to finish spark app and fail jenkins job, so throw exception.
  throw new RuntimeException("Hey Jenkins, please fail.")
}
```

## Behavior of above code

Spark application retried as of the retrying conf.
But I do not want to turn the retry off for the general purpose.
Above code is not an actual one but the flow is similar.

## Question

How can I stop spark gracefully then exit the main application exit with fail by programmatically in the application?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `System.exit(1)` will solve your problem.

```
if(resultDataframe.count() == 0){
   println("Hey Jenkins, please fail")
   System.exit(1)
   }
```

the above program will exited with `exit 1` with following message

```
Hey Jenkins, please fail
```

If the above approach does not work, then

In shell script, run your spark-submit and after that (with the above `System.exit(1)` code) and try to capture the output of the spark-submit command
using `$?` operator.

```
if [ $? -eq 1 ];
     exit 1
```

Comment: ` System.exit(1)` make a spark application retry even there is `spark.stop()` right before. Definitely.